# code manupulation does not work through javascript

Tags: javascript

Html containing simple div element with class container given some height. I want the height to be equal to window height through javascript.

```
<script >
    
        var container = document.querySelector('.container');
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;  

        container.style.height = windowHeight;

</script>
```

If I change the value with some random number it works but does not show an effect when putting 'windowHeight'.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with JavaScript? CSS is perfectly capable of it: `height: 100vh`.

Comment: You can try to append units ```container.style.height = windowHeight + "px"```

Answer (score 1):

`windowHeight` is a number, styles also require a unit.

Try adding `px` to your code:

```
container.style.height = windowHeight + 'px';
```

Working example:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

container.style.height = windowHeight + 'px';
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #500;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
```

Notes:

- If you want this to work after the page has been resized, you will need to listen for the resize event and rerun the code.
- If all you need to do is fill the background with a colour, the normal method would be to use CSS, and apply `height: 100vh` (Which means 100% of the view-port's height) which would work regardless of page resizes.